# Angular unit testing disable button attribute when form is invalid

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am disabling button when the form is invalid. When form is filled in properly button is enabled. It works, but I have problems with testing it:

I wrote the test like this:

```
 it('should have enabled button when title was provided', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.addTaskFormGroup.controls.title.setValue('TITLE');
        expect(component.addTaskFormGroup.invalid).toBeFalsy();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const createBtn = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[data-test-id="createTask"]');
        expect(createBtn.disabled).toBeFalse();
    });
```

It is properly setting form to invalid, but the last assertion returns `Expected true to be false.`

In html I have it stated like this:

```
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="addTaskFormGroup.invalid" data-test-id="createTask"  type="submit" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a unit test helper library that I wrote long ago.

```
export class TestHelper {
static isDisabled(fixture: ComponentFixture<any>, selector: string): boolean {
  const element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(selector));

  expect(element).toBeTruthy(`${selector} should exist`);

  return element.properties.disabled;
}

static verifyIsDisabled(fixture: ComponentFixture<any>, selector: string): void {
  const disabled = TestHelper.isDisabled(fixture, selector);

  expect(disabled).toBe(true, `${selector} should be disabled`);
}

static setTextInput(fixture: ComponentFixture<any>, selector: string, value: string): void {
  const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(selector));
  expect(input).toBeTruthy(`${selector} should exist`);

  input.nativeElement.value = value;
  input.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
}
}
```

In your test this would become something like

```
it('should have enabled button when title was provided', () => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  component.addTaskFormGroup.controls.title.setValue('TITLE');
  expect(component.addTaskFormGroup.invalid).toBeFalsy();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  TestHelper.verifyIsDisabled(fixture, '[data-test-id="createTask"]');
});
```

I would also recommend the use of `TestHelper.setTextInput` to interact with the html to set form values instead of calling into the component's methods. I try to interact with the component by its public interface, which is the html.

Along with that thought - if possible - avoid calls to confirm that `expect(component.addTaskFormGroup.invalid).toBeFalsy();`. Instead you should be able to see something based on that value in the html.

The goal is to be able to completely refactor the `component.ts` file while your unit tests won't have to change based on what you've named internal variables/methods.